# Linux CLI tool for auto-formatting (pretty printing) large SQL files

Tags: database, sql, formatter

I've got a large (3 GB) SQL file that came from a SQL dump.  Reading it is impossible because it's formatted poorly.  For example each table has a giant INSERT statement that is indecipherable.

Is there a CLI tool available for Linux that can automatically format this thing?  Maybe something like jq but operates on a SQL file instead of JSON?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392001/sql-string-formatter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335158/how-to-pretty-format-the-printing-of-sql-queries-in-sqlalchemy

Comment: Related: [Command line SQL formatter or beautifier - Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/85348/command-line-sql-formatter-or-beautifier)

Answer (score 1):

There used to be a few of them available, but I haven't tried any of them personally for a while. Therefore I do not know how well they can handle multi-gigabyte SQL dumps.

I remember, for [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js)/JavaScript there is [sql-formatter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sql-formatter).  See also the  [README on GitHub](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/sql-formatter#readme).

You could also search for "SQL beautifiers". The search results mention a lot of online-formatters, but these are targeted at smaller queries, single SQL statements. I haven't looked closely though. Maybe there is an offline beautifier among them.

Comment: Thanks yeah of all the online formatters, only one had a local tool and it was a "premium" tool.  I tried probably a dozen different tools I found on github, including one that I use in other places (prettier from npm) but it chokes at 2.5 GB of SQL

Comment: @Freedom_Ben: perhaps you can split the multi-GB SQL file manually into a few 100-MB Files, then try again. Split with sed, or perl, or some other tool. - Besides, In VScode you can also "Format Selection", but this would mean that the Editor opens/loads the file efficiently.