# Command line SQL formatter or beautifier

Tags: database, osx, offline, sql, formatter

I am looking for a command line SQL formatter = SQL prettifier = SQL beautifier (offline, *not* an online formatter) for Mac. The goal is to run it on the command line and also inside the editor ([Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs)) for SQL files under a few thousand lines.

**Related:**

Most of the posts below do not answer my question because of one or more of the following reasons: they were closed before they could accumulate enough quality answers; they are old; they refer mostly to online tools; they are related to other languages/operating systems:

- [What Free SQL Formatting Tools exist? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3310188/what-free-sql-formatting-tools-exist) (2010)
- [plsql - Good free offline PL/SQL formatter - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522040/good-free-offline-pl-sql-formatter) (2009)
- [sql server - Tidy for SQL - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093106/tidy-for-sql) (2009)
- [linux - SQL string formatter - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392001/sql-string-formatter) (2008)
- [python - How to pretty format the printing of SQL Queries in SQLAlchemy? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44335158/how-to-pretty-format-the-printing-of-sql-queries-in-sqlalchemy) (2017) (python-related)
- [postgresql - SQL Query Formatter - Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11074/sql-query-formatter) (2012)
- [database - Linux CLI tool for auto-formatting (pretty printing) large SQL files - Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/82791/linux-cli-tool-for-auto-formatting-pretty-printing-large-sql-files/82793#82793) (2022) (for Linux, while my question is for Mac)

Comment: Also see this related recent thread: [Command line SQL formatter or beautifier - Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/SQL/comments/11dkxv2/command_line_sql_formatter_or_beautifier/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Prettier](https://prettier.io/docs/en/plugins.html#community-plugins) integrates with editors and Git, has a command-line interface, and a SQL plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Try out `sqlformat`, shipped with [`sqlparse`](https://pypi.org/project/sqlparse/) Python library. The easiest way to install it is using [pipx](https://pypa.github.io/pipx/):

```
pipx install sqlparse
```

Here is an example of running it:

```
$ echo "sElECt address,country,fName FrOm tbl_Name Where f1=true aNd fname iS nOt null oRdEr bY fName aSc" \
   | sqlformat - --reindent --keywords upper
SELECT address,
       country,
       fName
FROM tbl_Name
WHERE f1=TRUE
  AND fname IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY fName ASC
```

To run it on a file, pass the file name instead of `-` :

```
sqlformat example.sql --reindent --keywords upper
```